# Destructor of a generic tree

Tags: c++, oop

I have a generic tree:

```
Node{
    int information;
    vector<Node*> childs;
}
```

And this is my destructor implementation:

```
~Node(){
    for(int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
        delete childs[i];
    }
```

The problem is that I'm allowing  childs to be the same. For example: NodeA has childs B,C,B,C,C. This break the destructor implementation as B can not be deleted twice.

What would be the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Consider using smart pointers, e. g. `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

First a small theoretical note: This isn´t a tree,
but a more generic graph, because trees don´t have cycles.

About your problem, a quick solution would be to sort all childs (by address); then you can easily recognize while iterating it where duplicates are, and just skip them. Like that:

```
if(childs.size() == 0) return;
std::sort(childs.begin(), childs.end());
childs.remove(std::unique(childs.begin(), childs.end()), childs.end());
for (auto& child : childs) delete child;
```

Comment: Ehm, the last element will be leaked if it's unique. After sort I'd go for:
`childs.remove(std::unique(childs.begin(), childs.end()), childs.end());`
`for (auto& child : childs) { delete child; }`
Or instead, as it is popular here, use a `shared_ptr` and have a default destructor.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by using `shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers in your vector which would do the management for you and you just need to clear the vector (which is what I would recommend), or either transferring the list of nodes to a set before deleting each, or maintaining a list of deleted nodes in the destructor you delete them, and checking for the existance of the pointer in the deleted list (a set could do this relatively efficiently).

```
vector<Node*> childs;
```

becomes

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> childs; //Note you'll need a space between >, and shared_ptr may be in tr1 or boost if you aren't using c++11 or higher
```

and the destructor is:

```
~Node(){ 
    childs.clear();
}
```

To use `shared_ptr` you will need to use `shared_ptr` to refer to the objects once they are created. So retrieving them, and the multiple insertion mechanism would need to use them as well.

Comment: ...and now the inserting is a problem, because creating completely independent shared_ptr won´t help at all.

Comment: @deviantfan, if they are exactly the same object, how are they inserted/referenced? If you aren't using raw pointers anymore, then the shared_ptr is passed around, and then they won't be completely independent shared_ptr. I thought that was obvious. So I'll have to explain that.

Comment: `I thought that was obvious.` If you use shared_ptr even outside from the tree yes ... I thought more like creating the shared_ptr inside the tree class because it got a raw pointer from outside.

Comment: @deviantfan, although using `shared_ptr` is more modern and easier to get right, your answer solves the OPs question